# share the full process of my own app uploading on my android kitkat phone

Tags: android

How do I upload my android project of eclipse into my android phone

Also
I'm not able to fetch file data from primary memory getting no error.

```
try {
    FileInputStream Fin=ctx.openFileInput("Home Expenses.txt");
    InputStreamReader is=new InputStreamReader(Fin);

    BufferedReader bf=new BufferedReader(is);
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    String line;
    while ((line = bf.readLine()) != null) {
        sb.append(line);
    }
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this," Data from file"+sb, 5).show();
```

Comment: add catch statement in your code and try to get out the error. I believe line ctx.openFileInput("Home Expenses.txt"); is causing problem because file name should not contain spaces.

Answer (score 0):

Steps to install .apk file on your device.

1. Go to bin folder of your project.
2. There you will find yourProjectName.apk file.
3. Copy that file and save to any place in your PC or laptop.
4. Now connect your device and transfer that .apk file to your device.
5. Now go to file manager section of your device and find that same .apk file.
6. Now you will be able to install that .apk file in your device.

Another approach:

1. Go to bin folder of your project.
2. There you will find yourProjectName.apk file.
3. Upload that .apk file to your dropbox.
4. From there you will get a link to download that file.
5. Now open the same link from your device browser.
6. Now you will be able to download and install the same on your device.

for the problem related to file content reading what I will suggest is create a assets folder in root directory of your project and copy your .txt file in into assets folder. Now use the following code to read content line by line.

```
BufferedReader reader
try{
    final InputStream file = getAssets().open("yourFileName.txt");
    reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(file));
    String line = reader.readLine();
    while(line != null){

    line = reader.readLine();
   }
  } catch(IOException ioe){
    ioe.printStackTrace();
  }
```